# Load multiple lists in to one datatable

Tags: c#, list, datatable

Hi I have two lists one is parent list and other one is child list And I need to load the data contain in both list to single Datatable is there are way to do that

```
public class Country
{
  string Name;
  string Countrycode
  list<Company> Companies=new list<Company>(); 
}

public class Company
{
  string ComapnyName;
  string Address1;
  string Address2;
  String Owner; 
}
```

when creating table it must be like this

```
Name       Countrycode  ComapnyName   Address1    Address2   Owner              
USA          001          Apple       Whereever   null       Jobbs  
Japan        002          Sony        Whereever   null       unknown
```

Comment: Why not just use the 2 objects independantly?
i.e. use the data from the Country object and the data / properties from the Company object when filling up yuor database? Perhaps you need to explain what it is you wanting a little clearer?

Comment: What if companies is empty, should you have a row with null in the company fields?

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem? You can use a loop:

```
DataTable tblCountries = new DataTable();
// add all columns ...
foreach(Country c in allCountries)
{
    if(c.Companies.Any())
    {
        foreach(var company in c.Companies)
        {
            var row = tblCountries.Rows.Add();
            row.SetField("Name", c.Name);
            row.SetField("Countrycode", c.Countrycode);
            row.SetField("CompanyName", company.CompanyName);
            // add the other company fields ...
        }
    }
    else  // add just the country and let the company cells be null
    {
        var row = tblCountries.Rows.Add();
        row.SetField("Name", c.Name);
        row.SetField("Countrycode", c.Countrycode);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to output the table in the way the op has requested?

Comment: @BobVale: in what way? OP wants to fill a table, he doesn't want to output it.

Comment: partially because it adds blank rows?

Comment: @BobVale: There are no blank rows in my approach. There are blank (null) company-fields if and only if there are no companies in  a country.

Comment: Yes, I read that as undesirable, ie inner join not left outer.  Also you'll get an exception if companies is null too

Comment: @BobVale: It's easy to change `c.Companies.Any()` to `c.Companies != null && c.Companies.Any()`. However, the list is initialized by default. Apart from that, there's no need to use Linq at all. In general, populating a `DataTable` is outside the remit of Linq. An exception is if you select a single table and you want to fill another table with the same schema from the result. Then `CopyToDataTable` might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use microsofts example of how to create a copy to datable method show here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

You can then do the following

```
Country.SelectMany(x => x.Companies
                         .Select(y => new { 
                                            x.Name,
                                            x.CountryCode,
                                            y.ComapnyName,
                                            y.Address1,
                                            y.Address2,
                                            y.Owner
                                          } )).CopyToDataTable();
```

PS copied the spelling of Comapny name not sure if you mean this!

**Update to deal with Companies being null**

If the companies property could be null:

```
Country.SelectMany(x => (x.Companies ?? Enumerable.Empty<Company>())
                         .Select(y => new { 
                                            x.Name,
                                            x.CountryCode,
                                            y.ComapnyName,
                                            y.Address1,
                                            y.Address2,
                                            y.Owner
                                          } )).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that he wants to create a `DataTable` from an `IEnumerable<Anonymous Type>`. Also, `Companies` could be empty but the `Country` should be added to the table anyway. That would throw an exception here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP has said they want to take a nested list structure and create a datatable from it?

Comment: But he hasn't mentioned that he cannot create the `DataTable` with the actual columns of the two classes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter at which point you can use the other copy to datatable overload that supports and existing table?

Comment: Only if the input is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and you cannot use it for an existing `DataTable`. You have to assign the table that's created by `CopyToDataTable` to the other reference.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, there are two overloads created in the msdn example, one that accepts a datatable, you just need to provide a table that matches the schema

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38337/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-bob-vale)